# Excluir os arquivos .bashrc, .bash_profile e .profile: quais as consequências?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bash

Estive tentando instalar o *Ruby* e o *Ruby on Rails* através do *RVM* mas durante o processo de instalação tive alguns probleminhas. Tentei desinstalar o *RVM* através do comandos :

```
rvm implode 

gem uninstall rvm
```

Após realizar esses comandos, achei que era para excluir os arquivos `.bashrc` ; `.bash_profile` ; `.profile` então o fiz.

Quando tentei reinstalar o RVM esses arquivos não retornaram. Como devo proceder, já que tenho que configurar o:

`.bashrc` :

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

`.bash_profile` :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

PS.: Estou iniciando no Ubuntu, com isso segui essas dicas inicialmente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system

Comment: So para comentar (:P): esses arquivos so influenciam o `shell` padrao, o `bash`. Voce pode tentar usar outros um dia.

Answer (score 4):

Esses arquivos são parte do sistema e servem para definir uma configuração ao terminal quando você o abre. O RVM os altera para se incluir na PATH e poder ser executado diretamente mesmo estando na sua home.

Existe uma cópia dos originais deles no diretório `/etc/skel` do sistema, pegue-os lá!

Comment: Olá Guilherme, neste diretório que você me indicou só conseguir encontrar os arquivos: .bashrc e o .profile. Onde encontro o .bash_profile ?

Answer (score 2):

Esses arquivos configuram o ambiente com preferências do usuário. A priori, apagar estes arquivos não afeta o sistema operacional, mas pode fazer com que comandos de executáveis comuns não sejam reconhecidos.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando ambiente gráfico e por consequência apenas terminais virtuais com *interactive shell*, o `.bash_profile` não deve fazer falta. Assim como o `.bashrc` e o `.profile` que servem para customizar o seu ambiente (digite `env` para ver todas as variáveis setadas), setar `aliases` e rodar algum programa que você goste quando abre um terminal novo (por exemplo, `mott` ou `cowsay` ), o `.bash_profile` só vai ser executado quando você utilizar uma *login shell* (`ssh` ou logando-se nos TTYs - ALT+F1 , ALT+F2, etc...)

Se você for realmente utilizar uma *login shell*, copie o `.bashrc` para o `.bash_profile`.

```
$ cd ~
$ cp .bashrc .bash_profile
```

Ou crie um link:

```
$ cd ~
$ ln -s .bashrc .bash_profile
```